# How to get all class methods of a class in Objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I have a class here

```
@interface Utils : NSObject

+(NSString *)getURL1;
+(NSString *)getURL2;
+(NSString *)getURL3;

@end

@implementation Utils

+(NSString *)getURL1
{
    return "url1";
}
+(NSString *)getURL2
{
    return "url2";
}
+(NSString *)getURL3
{
    return "url3";
}
@end
```

I need to read all methods of this class which returns 'url' as substring.
Can I do that ?

Comment: Whats the problem? Cant u just call all 3 at same time?

Comment: What do you want exactly. Can you show sample input and output you  expect?

Comment: What makes you sure that a method does not sometimes return @"abc1" and sometimes @"url1"?

Comment: @Tj3n : I have 500 methods in my class. Then i have to call 500 times, right ?

Comment: @BrammanandSoni u can create nested method and let them call each other on demand x_x...so call one, use many method at one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> need to read all methods of this class which returns 'url' as
>   substring. Can i do that ?

**NO**, you can not do it straightforward.

There could be other methods as well which will be returning something else. Also you need to call all the methods by yourself. Else a bit of *trick by using Obj-C runtime* to call all the 500 methods that the class contains.

If you are damn sure you will be having only few methods then call each of them store the returned value in an array, and filter out values begining with "url".

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import this class in any of the class you want these methods to work in as follows:

```
#import "Utils.h"
```

Now as this is an `NSObject` class, you just need to call the methods from that class as follows:

```
NSString * urlStringForYou = [Utils getURL1];
```

You are done. You will get the string in `urlStringForYou` as you want.